# jQuery Datepicker Not Working in IE8 (Other Posts Haven't Helped)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I have been all over many, many sites trying to figure out this issue to absolutely no avail.

The error I am getting (only in IE8. It works fine in Chrome, FF, IE9 and IE10) is using IE10 in the IE8 browser mode, but the business department testing this all have IE8 and the issues are the same.

**javascript runtime error: object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'**

- I have gone through and made sure that no other references to
  jQuery/jQuery-ui exist within the pages, and they do not.
- I have included the files in the correct order in the head portion of the master file. I have used both external links (to the google site and the jquery site) and the error is the same. These files are internal and work correctly. The custom jquery-ui file has all of the correct pieces, including datepicker, inside.

  ```
  <link id="datePickerStyle" runat="server" href="~/css/newblue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/modernizr.custom.93132.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```
- I have tried using the .noConflict() mode. Nothing different happened.

  ```
  <asp:TextBox ID="datebox" name="datepicker" runat="server" Text="" class="newblueCal" ></asp:TextBox>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=datebox.ClientID%>").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  minDate: 0,
  showOtherMonths: false,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  hideIfNoPrevNext: true
  });

  });     
  </script>
  ```

This datepicker is within a control, though I do have an instance of it that is not called from a control and it does the same thing. I am just looking for some input. I have been racking my brain and scouring the net for far to long on this problem, and I have not been able to fix it with any of the tips given.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

After tons of looking, fixing, etc... I found out that there was a jquery-compressed.js file that was causing the error. It was autosetting the jquery version to 1.1.2, as well as causing the datepicker issue.